# Pointer arithmetic is working but pointer de-referencing is not working

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic, pointer-to-pointer

I am trying to use pointer arithmetic to access pointer locations like an array. For testing same I wrote below code.

Now, I can see that pointer arithmetic is working because I can see incremented pointer address getting printed. But when I am de-referencing that pointer location to set some value then it is not working.

With my knowledge on C and pointers till now, I am not able to reason why pointer de-referencing is not working. If I was not able to get the increased the pointer location/address then atleast I would have understood that pointer arithmetic is not working, but when it is working then why pointer de-referencing is not working.

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int **DoublePtr;

void doublePointerTest();

int main(void)
{
    doublePointerTest();
}

void doublePointerTest()
{
    DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    *DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

    printf("Address of DoublePtr = %p\n", DoublePtr);
    printf("Address of *DoublePtr = %p\n", *DoublePtr);

    **DoublePtr = 100;

    *DoublePtr += 1;
    printf("+1 Address of *DoublePtr = %p\n", *DoublePtr);
    **DoublePtr = 1;

    *(*DoublePtr += 1) = 2;
    printf("+2 Address of *DoublePtr = %p\n", *DoublePtr);
    //**DoublePtr = 2;

    *DoublePtr += 1;
    printf("+3 Address of *DoublePtr = %p\n", *DoublePtr);
    **DoublePtr = 3;

   // *DoublePtr[4] = 4;
   // *DoublePtr[8] = 8;
   // *DoublePtr[3] = 3;
   // *DoublePtr[2] = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++, *DoublePtr += 1)
    {
        printf("%d.  ", i);
        printf("%d\n", **DoublePtr);
    }
}
```

**O/P:**

```
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_working): clang testing.c -o testing
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_working): ./testing 
Address of DoublePtr = 0x8cd4008
Address of *DoublePtr = 0x8cd4018
+1 Address of *DoublePtr = 0x8cd401c
+2 Address of *DoublePtr = 0x8cd4020
+3 Address of *DoublePtr = 0x8cd4024
0.  3
1.  0
2.  0
3.  0
4.  0
5.  0
6.  0
7.  0
8.  135105
9.  0
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_working):
```

---

**Updates:**

As per comments and answer, corrected my code from `DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int));` to `DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int*));` and tested but it gives same result.

Comment: @AlterMann Testing, but same result.

Comment: In the printf statements, "Address of" should say "Value of".    You are printing the address of the object being pointed to, not the address of the pointer.

Comment: The commented-out lines `*DoublePtr[4]` would also be a buffer overflow, you probably meant `(*DoublePtr)[4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code writes `100,1,2,3` to the first 4 locations of the 10 you malloc.

Then you print out the contents of the next 10 locations starting from the `3`: you see the `3`, then 6 uninitialized values, and then a buffer overflow.

You never print the values of the first 3 locations. Your dereferencing to set the value is working but you never output the result.

Perhaps you meant to set `*DoublePtr` back to its original value before printing?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs buddy, you nailed pretty much but I am still not getting expected o/p .. I used a temp variable to store double pointer address `int **tempDoublePtr = DoublePtr;` and then used this `tempDoublePtr` in FOR loop but still not working, did I do anything wrong?

Comment: @hagrawal Yes, you should have used `int *tempPtr = *DoublePtr;` and then used `tempPtr` in the loop. Saving `DoublePtr` is no use as `DoublePtr`'s value has not changed; it is `*DoublePtr` that changed.  Actually it would be better to leave `*DoublePtr` unchanged and use `tempPtr` whenever you want to have a movable pointer.

Comment: You nailed it mate, you really nailed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is wrong. You'll end up allocating wrong amount of memory there. You need to change it to

```
 DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

or, for better,

```
DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof *DoublePtr );
```

Also, always check the return value of `malloc()` to ensure success before using the returned pointer.

That said, another problem is, you kind of ignored the side-effect of using `+=`. It actually modifies the content of the left operand. So, your `*DoublePtr` is increased every time you use `+=` on it.

After that, without re-setting it to the original start pointer, you kept on doing `+=` on it in the later loop. This causes two-folded issue

1. As `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory, in the loop, you're trying to read *all* uninitialized memory, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. As you've not reset the pointer, after the 6th iteration, you're actually going out of bounds, which again invokes UB.

Comment: Testing, but same result.

Comment: "*So, your *DoublePtr is increased every time you use += on it.*" This is what I am trying to do, that's the way I want to access a pointer just like an array by using pointer arithmetic .. @M. M has given right direction ..

Comment: @hagrawal did you miss the _re-setting_ part? That's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Means ?? Going out of bounds is definitely bad and I will correct it but my problem is that my loop is not starting from beginning but address left in pointer after 3 pointer increment .. I tried to use a temp pointer to hold the original double address `*DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); int **tempDoublePtr = DoublePtr;`  and then use `tempDoublePtr` in FOR loop but no help ..

Comment: Thanks buddy for your valuable inputs. +1 but cannot accept because @M. M has nailed it till last brick.

Comment: @hagrawal Sure, no issues. Cheers!!

Comment: I know your allocating memory for int pointer was 110% right but an interesting thing is that after the fix if I revert back to `DoublePtr = malloc(sizeof(int));` then also my code is working as expected .. Probably because int and a pointer, both are of 4 bytes (*I am running code on a 32 bit box*) ..

Answer (score 1):

I can see an issue here at a quick glance. Why are you allocating the double pointer? You should allocate a pointer and then point the double pointer to it or pass the memory address of the allocation to the double pointer.

```
int* pointer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int** DoublePtr = &pointer;
```

OR

```
int DoublePtr = &malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

I would recommend using the first method as it is more standard and easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your time to answer.